# gremlin console gui object browser

Tags: groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop

Whilst learning about the gremlin console, i came across the `:inspect` command.

The help say's *Inspect a variable or the last result with the GUI object browser*

But when i run the command i get the message

> ERROR: Running in AWT Headless mode, 'inspect' is not available.

I tried investigating further about what the **GUI object browser** is but came up with nothing.

Has anyone got any further details on what the GUI object browser is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:inspect` is an option that comes from `groovysh` which is the shell interpreter that the Gremlin Console is based on. You can read a little more about `groovysh` in the [Apache Groovy docs](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-inspect) and this [article](https://www.developer.com/lang/article.php/10924_3657751_2/What-Groovy-Can-Do-For-You.htm). The object browser doesn't appear to work from the Gremlin Console, and it is not documented in the Apache TinkerPop [console commands docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_console_commands).